# Is there a work around for invalid octal digit in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, octal

I'm trying to create an array which will hold the hours in a day so I can loop through it for a clock.

I have:

```
int hourArray[24] = {12, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02,
                     03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11};
```

I am getting the error on the following numbers in order `08, 09, 08, 09`.

It tells me:

> Error: invalid octal digit

I've never run into this before and I'm wondering if there is any way around it?

Comment: Literals beginning with `0` are considered by the compiler to be octal, align them with spaces instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure: don't use leading 0s when you don't mean octal:

```
int hourArray[24] = {12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
```

Don't forget that you're only specifying the *numbers* in the array - not any particular text representation of the number. (So if you write `012` that's equivalent to writing `10` - you'll end up with the same *number*.) If you want to format those numbers with a leading 0 later that's an entirely different aspect of the code.

Comment: What if you want the number zero but you don't mean octal?

Comment: @KerrekSB : just 0 would be fine instead of 00